# How to test the `Mosquitto` server?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am new to `Mosquitto` and `MQTT`, I downloaded the `Mosquitto` server library but I do not know how to  test it.

Is there any way to test the `Mosquitto` server?

Comment: A server can "smoke tested" (gross verification that it is running \ available): this is quick test to verify that the application is installed and running (not necessarily functional as it may need to be configured).   In general, Smoke-tests are performed before a functional verification test are performed.   An example is provided below

Answer (score 151, accepted):

In separate terminal windows do the following:

1. Start the broker:

   ```
   mosquitto
   ```
2. Start the command line subscriber:

   ```
   mosquitto_sub -v -t 'test/topic'
   ```
3. Publish test message with the command line publisher:

   ```
   mosquitto_pub -t 'test/topic' -m 'helloWorld'
   ```

As well as seeing both the subscriber and publisher connection messages in the broker terminal the following should be printed in the subscriber terminal:

```
test/topic helloWorld
```

EDIT:

It is worth pointing out that from v2.0.0 of Mosquitto it will only be listening for connections on the loopback interface by default. If you want to access the broker from machines other than the one it is installed on you will need to edit the config file (and pass it to the broker with the `-c` option e.g. `mosquitto -c /path/to/mosquitto.conf`) to enable listening on other interfaces. Details can be found in the v2.0.0 release notes [here](https://mosquitto.org/blog/2020/12/version-2-0-0-released/)

Comment: Actually, when i write mosquitto in the terminal, it says that no such command is recognised

Comment: Sounds like you haven't installed it. Update the original question with details of what steps you have actually done, then we may be able to help

Comment: i just downlaoded the zip file and unzipped it, and there is no any excutable file to run

Comment: Which zip file for which platform?

Comment: You haven't actually answered my question, but I'm going to assume you have downloaded the source code. In which case I suggest read the file called compiling.txt or go back to the mosquitto download page and download the windows binary listed lower down the page (http://mosquitto.org/files/binary/win32/mosquitto-1.3.5-install-win32.exe), in which case as  it will be installed as a service you can miss out step 1

Comment: ok now i downloaded the binary file and installed it, but neither of commands posted are acceptable still unrecognisable

Comment: The mosquitto_pub and mosquitto_sub commands get installed to C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto (on Win 8) and you'll need to ensure that the service is running. Works fine here.

Comment: if you installed mosquitto on Mac by Homebrew, the mosquitto locates in sbin folder

Comment: @xmkevincheb hmm, that seams wrong, there is no reason why mosquitto should have to run as root/admin

Answer (score 28):

Start the Mosquitto Broker 
Open the terminal and type

`mosquitto_sub -h 127.0.0.1 -t topic`

Open another terminal and type 
`mosquitto_pub -h 127.0.0.1 -t topic -m "Hello"`

Now you can switch to the previous terminal and there you can able to see the "Hello" Message.One terminal acts as publisher and another one subscriber.

Comment: What value is there is just repeating the answer already given?

Answer (score 16):

To test and see if you can access your MQTT server from outside world (outside of your VM or local machine), you can install one of the MQTT publishing and monitoring tools such as [MQTT-Spy](https://github.com/kamilfb/mqtt-spy/wiki/Overview) on your outside-world machine and then subscribe for '#" (meaning all the topics).

You can follow this by the method @hardillb mentioned in his answer above and test back and forth such as this:

On the machine with Mosquitto Server running,
[image]

On the outside-word machine with mqtt-spy running,
[image]

I have mainly mentioned mqtt-spy since it's multi-platform and easy to use. You can go with any other tool really. 
And also to my knowledge to run the `mosquitto_sub` and `mosquitto_pub` you need to have **mosquitto-clients** installed on your Linux machine running the test (in my case Ubuntu) which can be done easily by,

`sudo apt-get install mosquitto-clients`

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Windows, open up a command prompt and type '**netstat -an**'.

If your server is running, you should be able to see the port 1883.

[image: cmd displaying mosquitto port]

If you cannot go to Task Manager > Services and start/restart the Mosquitto server from there. If you cannot find it here too, your installation of Mosquitto has not been successful.

A more detailed [tutorial](https://sivatechworld.wordpress.com/2015/06/11/step-by-step-installing-and-configuring-mosquitto-with-windows-7/) for setting up Mosquitto with Windows / is linked here.

Answer (score 1):

The OP has not defined the scope of testing, however, simple (gross) 'smoke testing' an install should be performed before any time is invested with functionality testing.

## How to test if application is installed ('smoke-test')

Log into the `mosquitto` server's command line and type:

```
mosquitto
```

If mosquitto is installed the machine will return:

```
 mosquitto version 1.4.8 (build date Wed, date of installation) starting
 Using default config.
 Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883
```

Comment: @gatorback  I don't  know.what is the main reason of such response.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to have an GUI based broker testing without installing any tool you can use Hive Mqtt web socket for testing your `Mosquitto` server

just visit http://www.hivemq.com/demos/websocket-client/ and enter server connection details.

If you got connected means your server is configured properly.

You can also test `publish` and `subscribe` of messages using this mqtt web socket

Comment: That only works if you have configured a Websocket Listener in your mosquitto.conf file. By default mosquitto does not start a Websocker listener.

Comment: Yes, I forgot that point, this will not work with out of box installation, I will update question, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for a way to do this Postman has added MQTT support. It is currently in beta, but you can find more information about how to get started [here](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/mqtt-client/mqtt-client-overview/).

Disclaimer: I work for Postman on this client.

Comment: It's not about Postman. But I see You like Postman.