# smoke testing MQTT server installed via docker?

Tags: docker, service, mosquitto

Within Raspbian: I have installed Mosquito via docker per:

https://www.schaerens.ch/raspi-setting-up-mosquitto-mqtt-broker-on-raspberry-pi-docker/

In the past I have installed it without docker and tested it per:

[Mosquito (MQTT) Service Smoke test](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57634477)

Can I expect the  `service mosquitto status` to provide status?  If not what is the procedure to perform the equivalent?

[image]

Comment: `mosquitto` command will not provide the status. As you have installed it with docker. You can use the `docker ps` command to list all the active containers. Based on the `status` field, it has been running for 2 hours, which means Mosquito MQTT is running as well. `docker ps -a` this will show all the active and in-active containers. If the status is `Exited` then it means the container is not active. `docker ps` is the equivalent, but it will show all (you can use filters along with it). See more [docker ps](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/)

Answer (score 1):

No, the `service` command is for checking on things running natively on the host OS, using `init.d` or `system.d` (in the case of Raspberry Pi OS it will be system.d)

If the container shows up in the output of `docker ps` then is it running which means that the config file (if provided) is at least syntactically correct, if you supply a incorrect config file then the container will stop straight away as the only thing that keeps it running is the mosquitto process.

You may do better using parts 2 & 3 in the accepted answer to [How to test the `Mosquitto` server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716279/how-to-test-the-mosquitto-server/)