# Arduino does not connect to Mosquitto On both windows and ubuntu

Tags: arduino, esp8266, mosquitto

I'm trying to connect an ESP8266 to my laptop to a mosquitto broker. I have tried both windows and ubuntu but none worked!.

**This is the windows part:**

The mosquitto broker is online:

```
C:\Program Files\Mosquitto>mosquitto -v
1625556778: mosquitto version 2.0.11 starting
1625556778: Using default config.
1625556778: Starting in local only mode. Connections will only be possible from clients running on this machine.
1625556778: Create a configuration file which defines a listener to allow remote access.
1625556778: For more details see https://mosquitto.org/documentation/authentication-methods/
1625556778: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1625556778: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1625556778: mosquitto version 2.0.11 running
```

This is the arduino code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

// Update these with values suitable for your network.

const char* ssid = "Laurium";
const char* password = "pass";
//const char* mqtt_server = "192.168.1.35"; I tried this as well
IPAddress mqtt_server = (192, 168, 1, 35);

WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);
long lastMsg = 0;
char msg[50];
int value = 0;

void setup_wifi() {

  delay(10);
  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  randomSeed(micros());

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  Serial.print("Message arrived [");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print("] ");
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();

  // Switch on the LED if an 1 was received as first character
  if ((char)payload[0] == '1') {
   digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, LOW);   // Turn the LED on (Note that LOW is the voltage level
    // but actually the LED is on; this is because
    // it is active low on the ESP-01)
  } else {
   digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, HIGH);  // Turn the LED off by making the voltage HIGH
 }

}

void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    // Create a random client ID
    String clientId = "ESP8266Client-";
    clientId += String(random(0xffff), HEX);
    // Attempt to connect
    if (client.connect(clientId.c_str())) {
      Serial.println("connected");
      // Once connected, publish an announcement...
      client.publish("outTopic", "hello world");
      // ... and resubscribe
      client.subscribe("inTopic");
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(BUILTIN_LED, OUTPUT);     // Initialize the BUILTIN_LED pin as an output
  Serial.begin(9600);
  setup_wifi();
  client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
  client.setCallback(callback);
}

void loop() {

  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
  client.loop();

  long now = millis();
  if (now - lastMsg > 2000) {
    lastMsg = now;
    ++value;
    snprintf (msg, 50, "hello world #%ld", value);
    Serial.print("Publish message: ");
    Serial.println(msg);
    client.publish("outTopic", msg);
  }
}
```

This the output on the terminal:

```
WiFi connected
IP address: 
192.168.137.90
Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
```

My laptop local IP: `192.168.1.35`

So it successfully connects to the WIFI but cannot find the broker.
I also followed [This](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/solved-mosquitto-broker-help/650374/5) thread but didn't work. I even added 1883 port as an inbound port in the windows firewall with a new TCP rule. I also entirely disabled the firewall or switched to an older version of mosquitto where remote clients were allowed by default All to no avail.

**The ubuntu part**:
Here I modified the code slightly. I also added the `ping` command so I could check if my esp8266 can ping the google? And can it ping the destination mosquitto server IP or not?
I installed mosquito on my ubuntu vmware and passed the vmware IP obtained by IP config command in my host machine, the windows.
I also tested my mosquitto on ubuntu and it worked fine with test publisher-subscriber on ubuntu.
On ubuntu unlike windows, pining the mosquitto IP was successful but the mosquitto terminal did not show anything.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <ESP8266Ping.h>
// Update these with values suitable for your network.

const char* ssid = "Laurium";
const char* password = "pass";
//const char* mqtt_server = "192.168.186.1";

IPAddress mqtt_server = (192, 168, 186, 1);
//IPAddress mqtt_server = (192, 168, 15, 1);


WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);
long lastMsg = 0;
char msg[50];
int value = 0;

void setup_wifi() {

  delay(10);
  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  randomSeed(micros());

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  Serial.print("Message arrived [");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print("] ");
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();

  // Switch on the LED if an 1 was received as first character
  if ((char)payload[0] == '1') {
   digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, LOW);   // Turn the LED on (Note that LOW is the voltage level
    // but actually the LED is on; this is because
    // it is active low on the ESP-01)
  } else {
   digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, HIGH);  // Turn the LED off by making the voltage HIGH
 }

}

void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    // Create a random client ID
    String clientId = "ESP8266Client-";
    clientId += String(random(0xffff), HEX);
    // Attempt to connect
    if (client.connect(clientId.c_str())) {
      Serial.println("connected");
      // Once connected, publish an announcement...
      client.publish("outTopic", "hello world");
      // ... and resubscribe
      client.subscribe("inTopic");
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      bool ret = Ping.ping(mqtt_server);
      Serial.println(ret);
      Serial.println(Ping.ping("www.google.com"));
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(BUILTIN_LED, OUTPUT);     // Initialize the BUILTIN_LED pin as an output
  Serial.begin(9600);
  setup_wifi();
  client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
  client.setCallback(callback);
}

void loop() {

  //IPAddress ip (192, 168, 0, 1); // The remote ip to ping


  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
  client.loop();

  long now = millis();
  if (now - lastMsg > 2000) {
    lastMsg = now;
    ++value;
    snprintf (msg, 50, "hello world #%ld", value);
    Serial.print("Publish message: ");
    Serial.println(msg);
    client.publish("outTopic", msg);
  }
}
```

This time, the output was this:

```
WiFi connected
IP address: 
192.168.137.109
Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
1
1
```

Unlike windows, pinging the IP where the mosquitto server resides is successful, but still not establishing any connection.

If I could work with any of the windows or ubuntu mosquitto servers it is fine.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you verified by other means that your Broker is responding and allowing connections?

Comment: @Nino No. What should I do to make sure?

Comment: https://lormenyoh.medium.com/sending-sensor-data-to-mosquitto-on-windows-from-nodemcu-68932e2d4082 I followed this

Comment: Search SO for "How to test the Mosquitto server".

Comment: @Nino I did refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716279/how-to-test-the-mosquitto-server   
But after the command mosquitto everything freezes and doesn't go forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully ran mosquitto on Ubuntu vmware.
First of all I put my VM network on bridging and connected my laptop and my node to a same wifi so they both reside on a same network and can communicate.
Second I added these two lines to the `mosquitto.conf` file:

```
listener 1883 0.0.0.0
allow_anonymous true
```

and saved the file. The conf file resides in `/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf`
Then I manually shut down the mosquitto with `sudo service mosquitto stop` and restart it with `sudo service mosquitto start`.
you can use the `netstat -tulpn` in another terminal to ensure that you have a tcp listener on `127.0.0.1:1883`. This worked fine for me.
Meanwhile I still can not do the same on windows.

Answer (score 2):

From the output on startup:

```
1625556778: Starting in local only mode. Connections will only be possible from clients running on this machine. 
1625556778: Create a configuration file which defines a listener to allow remote access. 
1625556778: For more details see https://mosquitto.org/documentation/authentication-methods/
```

The important part is **Starting in local only mode**

From version 2.0 onward mosquitto needs to be explicitly configured to accept connections from anything other than localhost and needs to be set to accept connections that do not pass a username and password.

You can add the following to the mosquitto.conf

```
allow_anonymous true
listener 1883 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Hello. I checked the config file. All lines are started with # which as indicated are comments. I added these two lines to the last rows but the issue persists and the local-only mode still exist

Comment: Have you ensured that you are actually starting mosquitto with the modified config file? mosquitto does not automatically read any default config files

Comment: I used the command mosquitto -c mosquitto.conf   But after I press enter it freezes and never comes out. 
Meanwhile, I downloaded mosquito version 1.5.8 and after running, there's nothing about local only mode, but again the esp8266 cannot connect nor ping the ip